# edgeID is returned as alpha numeric instead of long in Janusgraph

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph, tinkerpop3

I use the following code to create an edge

```
        Edge e = this.g
            .V(fromId) // get vertex of id given for the source
            .as("fromVertex") // label as fromVertex to be accessed later
            .V(toId) // get  vertex of id given for destination
            .coalesce( // evaluates the provided traversals in order and returns the first traversal that emits at least one element
                inE(label) // check incoming edge of label given
                    .where( // conditional check to check if edge exists
                        outV() // get destination vertex of the edge to check
                            .as("fromVertex")), // against staged vertex
                addE(label) // add edge if not present
                    .from("fromVertex"))
            .next(); // end traversal to commit to graph

        System.out.println(Long.parseLong(e.id().toString());
```

This prints edgeId as `1lb-394-36d-38`. As a result of this, I am getting NumberFormatException. I thought all ids are long by default. Is there something I need to configure?

This is my current configuration

```
gremlin.graph=org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory

storage.backend=berkeleyje
storage.directory=jgex/berkeleyje

index.jgex.backend=lucene
index.jgex.directory=jgex/lucene
```

I tried the same on gremlin console, I am getting a long ID as expected, irrespective of how many times I execute. I did this to see if `coalesce` is causing some issue

```
gremlin> g.V(0L).as("fromVertex").V(2L).coalesce(inE("MIXES_WITH").where(outV().as("fromVertex")), addE("MIXES_WITH").from("fromVertex")).next().id()
==>6

gremlin> g.V(0L).as("fromVertex").V(2L).coalesce(inE("MIXES_WITH").where(outV().as("fromVertex")), addE("MIXES_WITH").from("fromVertex")).next().id()
==>6

gremlin> g.V(0L).as("fromVertex").V(2L).coalesce(inE("MIXES_WITH").where(outV().as("fromVertex")), addE("MIXES_WITH").from("fromVertex")).next().id()
==>6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edge IDs in JanusGraph are stored using a special class called RelationIdentifier that contains a lot more information than just the ID itself. The ID of that class is a "UUID like" identifier. You can get other information from the class. Below is an example using a simple 'inmemory' JanusGraph from the Gremlin Console.

```
gremlin> g.addV('a').as('a').addV('b').as('b').addE('test').from('a').to('b')
==>e[16p-360-2dx-9jk][4104-test->12368]

gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('a').outE().next().class
==>class org.janusgraph.graphdb.relations.StandardEdge

gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('a').outE().id().next().class
==>class org.janusgraph.graphdb.relations.RelationIdentifier

gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('a').outE().id().next().class.methods
==>public long org.janusgraph.graphdb.relations.RelationIdentifier.getTypeId()
==>public long org.janusgraph.graphdb.relations.RelationIdentifier.getOutVertexId()
==>public long org.janusgraph.graphdb.relations.RelationIdentifier.getInVertexId()
==>public long[] org.janusgraph.graphdb.relations.RelationIdentifier.getLongRepresentation()
==>public long org.janusgraph.graphdb.relations.RelationIdentifier.getRelationId()
==>public static org.janusgraph.graphdb.relations.RelationIdentifier org.janusgraph.graphdb.relations.RelationIdentifier.get(int[])
==>public static org.janusgraph.graphdb.relations.RelationIdentifier org.janusgraph.graphdb.relations.RelationIdentifier.get(long[])
==>public boolean org.janusgraph.graphdb.relations.RelationIdentifier.equals(java.lang.Object)
==>public java.lang.String org.janusgraph.graphdb.relations.RelationIdentifier.toString()
==>public int org.janusgraph.graphdb.relations.RelationIdentifier.hashCode()
==>public static org.janusgraph.graphdb.relations.RelationIdentifier org.janusgraph.graphdb.relations.RelationIdentifier.parse(java.lang.String)
==>public final void java.lang.Object.wait(long,int) throws java.lang.InterruptedException
==>public final native void java.lang.Object.wait(long) throws java.lang.InterruptedException
==>public final void java.lang.Object.wait() throws java.lang.InterruptedException
==>public final native java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()
==>public final native void java.lang.Object.notify()
==>public final native void java.lang.Object.notifyAll()

gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('a').outE().id().next().getRelationId()   
==>1537
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not know this.

Comment: Do vertex IDs are always integers? And do edge IDs are always UUID?

Comment: For now they are always LONG values. There is some interesting discussion here https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/1221

Comment: Which janusgraph version are you using? We were using janusgraph version 0.5.2 and we didn't face this issue before but now we are upgrading to janusgraph 1.0.0 and now seeing this issue.