# Types of IDs of vertices and edges

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, tinkerpop3

Are the vertices always have integer IDs? Vertex ids are always like `12212`
Are the edges always have UUID or string-like IDs? Edge ids are always like `"16p-360-2dx-9jk"`

Comment: Please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67759285/edgeid-is-returned-as-alpha-numeric-instead-of-long-in-janusgraph/67776644?noredirect=1#comment121516046_67776644

Comment: what about vertex IDs? Should they always be integers?

Comment: For now they are always LONG values. There is some interesting discussion here https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/1221

Comment: I added an answer to try and summarize this conversation.

Answer (score 3):

The subject of how IDs are managed in JanusGraph seems to be a regular topic of confusion. It would probably good to add something to the official documentation that is easy to find a clearly describes the behavior.

Vertex IDs are LONG values. Currently you cannot supply a string or UUID as a vertex ID.

Edge IDs are handled a little differently using a RelationIdentifier as described in this answer: [edgeID is returned as alpha numeric instead of long in Janusgraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67759285/edgeid-is-returned-as-alpha-numeric-instead-of-long-in-janusgraph/67776644?noredirect=1#comment121516046_67776644)